# Pass selected row from table to prepare for segue Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

How can i pass this line to my prepare for segue method?

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.secondsTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
  if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[MyViewController class]]) {
    MyViewController * dvc = (MyViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSInteger row = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
    dvc.seconds =[[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];   
  }
}
```

i had a time picker before and converted it to table so i still have `NSInteger row = [self.timePicker selectedRowInComponent:0];` in my code how can i successfully pass the selected row from my table view into my prepare fro segue method.

i have tried to pass it like this with no luck:- i get crash

```
NSInteger row = [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:[[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
dvc.seconds =[[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
```

please help

Comment: Can you attach tour crashlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set an object to NSInteger i.e. row in code
LET me modify your code

```
NSInteger row1 = [[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row];// Get row value
NSInteger row = [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row1];// Error line
dvc.seconds =[[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];// Use to have object
```

This is what you're doing.

Change code from :

```
NSInteger row = [self.pickerData objectAtIndex:[[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
        dvc.seconds =[[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
```

To :

```
dvc.seconds = [[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:[[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row] intValue];
```

OR

```
NSInteger row = [[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row];// Get row value
dvc.seconds =[[self.pickerData objectAtIndex:row] intValue];// Use to have object
```

Comment: thanks just saw your edit and it works but one thing is when i select 4 from my table it logs 3 in my NSLOG for `NSInteger row = [[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row];// Get row value` instead of 4 how can i get 4

Comment: Look here it gives you zero based indexing which is applicable on Arrays also i.e. in array **4th value** has **index 3** so just let it pass but still you want to get 4 so you have to add it manually.

Comment: @Joey121 do like this `NSInteger row = [[self.secondsTable indexPathForSelectedRow] row] + 1;`